# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter not working with WKWebView playback

Tags: ios, wkwebview, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm using `WKWebView` to play audio/video and am looking to set custom `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` `nowPlayingInfo`, but `WKWebView` appears to override any settings that I make. Has anyone been able to add custom lockscreen controls and metadata while using `WKWebView`?

Here is a condensed example of the code that I am using:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

// ... create the WKWebView and play the video ...

NSMutableDictionary * const mutableNowPlayingInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
mutableNowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]            = [playlistItem videoCreator]  ?: @"";
mutableNowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]             = [playlistItem videoName]     ?: @"";
mutableNowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration]  = [playlistItem videoDuration] ?: @(0.0);
mutableNowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = @(1.0);

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter * const infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
[infoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:mutableNowPlayingInfo];
```

Note that `-remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:` is also overridden as necessary in my `AppDelegate` class.

Also note that this works fine if the `WKWebView` is swapped out for, say, an `AVPlayer` or `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: I have similar problem :-(

Comment: For what it's worth, I contacted Apple using a DTS ticket and they responded that this was by design. Doesn't look like there is a resolution at this time.

Comment: @AaronWojnowski : Any solution for this ?

Comment: Nope :( @Nishan29

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution? 1.5 years passed...

Comment: Unfortunately not @KeshaAntonov

Comment: @AaronWojnowski find any solution for it bcz i'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview